# Turn a text area into an array by line and then append it to a div using Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have tried loads of code and have left it commented out in the javascript file.
I want to take the contents of a textarea (defined by the user) and turn it into an array. I will then use a for loop to append each element to a new div. All when button1 is clicked.

I have set up a jsfiddle for this

http://jsfiddle.net/34uBW/1/

I have looked at the other posts on here and I think I am missing something do I need to use php? ( never used php before)

Thanks

js looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('#button').click(function()
{    
     var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
     var $newdiv = "<div class='draggable'>" + toAdd + "</div>";
     $("#1").append($($newdiv).draggable());


}
);

$('#button1').click(function()
{
   /* //var yes = $('input[name=myname]').val();
    //var yes = $('input[name=myname]').val().split('\n');
   var yes = document.getElementById('textarea').value.split('\n');
   //var yes = $('#textarea')[0].value.split('\n');        
   var $newdiv1 = "<div class='draggable'>" + yes[0] + "</div>";
    $("#1").append($($newdiv1).draggable());
    var lines = $('#textarea').val().split(/\n/);
    var texts = []
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    // only push this line if it contains a non whitespace character.
    if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
    texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
    }
    }

    alert(JSON.stringify(texts));​*/

}
);





});
```

Comment: What is defining the split for each array entry, is it a new line (`\n`)? See this method: [split(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: yeah a new line can I combine that code with my jquery? do I just put that inside the click button function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
var lines = $("textarea").val().split(/\n/g);      //Split the lines
for(var i=0; i < lines.length; i++){               //Loop through the Array
    var ele = $("<p>");                            // ├─ Create a node
    ele.html(lines[i]);                            // ├─ Put in the text
    $("#opt").append(ele);                         // └─ Append it
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Ge2yF/
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Ge2yF/16

This will split the value of the textarea by `\n` (newline) into an Array, then append it in a `div`.

Comment: thias is awesome just tryoing to get it to work with my code now all work but need to make the new ele draggable!!  Cheers

Comment: @Freg - `$(ele).draggable()` will do the trick. [Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Ge2yF/8/).

Comment: yeah was have trouble because i didnt link it to the Jqueryui

Comment: @Freg - Hi Freg, if you find this answer to be helpful, you can accept this answer.

Comment: Cheers it work in fiddle but not if i split it into file on my computer do I need to include anything else in the javascript file?

Comment: @Freh - You will need to include jQuery, jQuery UI, and this code of course.

Comment: If you were going to append like that, it would be better for performance (especially if building lists of things, like dozens/hundreds of tweets, or a chapter worth of paragraphs), if you were to cache the value of `$("#opt")` as a variable, above the loop. jQuery has worked hard to improve the performance of asking for DOM elements (after the first time), but not caching DOM elements (or in this case, asking jQuery to constantly check entity-tables for the same node) still gets very expensive. And the only change needed is: `lines = ..., opt = $("#opt"); for(...){ ... opt.append(ele); }`

Comment: @Derek Hi Derek i still can't get this to work using three seperate files or even one file! the code i am using is working on jsfiddle

Comment: @Freg - Glad it works. It's a very common mistake people make, including me :)